# how to access android samsung device data/local/tmp path for unrooted device

Tags: android

We are trying to access the path data/local/tmp path through adb for unrooted samsung device. It is getting  permission denied. But the same path we are able to access in unrooted motorola,lenovo,micromax devices.

Please suggest us.Thanks in advance.

Comment: just tried on Nexus 4 and cant access too... looks like someone changed Android data folder permission ^^

Comment: How to change the folder permissions @PozzoApps

Comment: Only before compiling or on rooted devices. But why do you need exactly this folder?

Comment: If you mean `/data/local/tmp` then that is not possible.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to define data path in another way? @ greenapps